# std::wstring to rapidJson

Tags: c++, rapidjson, wstring

Hi I have `std::wstring Var_;` which is getting filled with json data something like this:

```json
{
  "event": "pull",
  "eventOccurred": "1642404339906526100",
  "Containers": [],
  "eventReported": 132868779492360000
}
```

My need is to get this Json data to copy into rapidjson::Document variable . How can I do that in c++?

Comment: `std::string` and `std::wstring` should interoperate, hence the duplicate. If the linked quesiton does not answer your own, please [edit] your question to explain how the fact that you are working with `std::wstring` makes it specific.

Comment: Agree.. string to rapidjson::Document will also help? which is the question/link which has the answer?